# How can I get whole (selected) objects from multiselect - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-ngmodel, ngfor

I'm trying to get out whole objects from `multiselect dropdown`, which I added to my angular template.

But I don't know how to do it, I get id's without problems, but when I try with whole object I can't get it and it shows in console `[object Object]`.

```
<!-- Select All option -->
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-form-label col-lg-3">Roles:</label>
<div class="col-lg-9">
  <select id="applicationModuleFormSelect" name="applicationModuleFormSelect"  [(ngModel)]="amf" class="form-control multiselect-select-all" multiple="multiple" data-fouc>
    <option *ngFor="let amf of appModuleForms;" [value]="amf">{{amf.title}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /select All option -->

 onSubmit() {
    var selectedAppForms = $('#applicationModuleFormSelect').val();
    console.log((selectedAppForms));
}
```

As you can see I wrote `[value]="amf"`, and in console I got this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Also if I apply `JSON.stringify` I'm getting similar results:

```
["1: Object","3: Object"]
```

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Try giving different name to ngModel like `[(ngModel)]="selectedItems"` and then print that on submit. You should be declaring `selectedItems` in your component.

Comment: @AmitChigadani can you provide more details please..

Comment: Use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`

Comment: @billy_56 Check this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eysgxw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @AmitChigadani check for my edit please, example is almost identical but I cant see the value..

Comment: @billy_56 Did you also change `onSubmit()`?

Comment: @AmitChigadani thanks for your help man but it's probably plugin multiselect which cancel my binding! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[(ngModel)]="selectedData"`

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugnscj?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-form-label col-lg-3">Roles:</label>
<div class="col-lg-9">
  <select id="applicationModuleFormSelect" name="applicationModuleFormSelect"  [(ngModel)]="selectedData" class="form-control multiselect-select-all" multiple="multiple" data-fouc>
    <option *ngFor="let amf of appModuleForms;" [value]="amf">{{amf.title}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please check for my edit, answer is almost identical but I cant see any value :/

Comment: thanks for your help guys but it's probably plug multiselect which cancel my binding but vote up anyway!